# Error while running MongoDB (i.e. the mongod process) manually as a background process

Tags: mongodb

After installing mongodb using Homebrew I started it by running this in the terminal

`brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`

which worked just fine after stopping it and I further
tried to run MongoDB (i.e. the mongod process) manually as a background process, by running this

`mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork`

and I got this error

````
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.


forked process: 43989

ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14

To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.```
````

Comment: And what do you get when you start without `--fork` as adviced by the error message?

Comment: Nothing its returning me back ,                                                          hariskhan@HARISs-MacBook-Air ~ % mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf       
I'm getting this --> hariskhan@HARISs-MacBook-Air ~ %

Comment: Check the logfile, typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` Location is defined in the config file.

Comment: Thanks but I got it, I did this-->                                                                                     sudo mongod --dbpath System/Volumes/Data/data